# how to send string data into a javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I am using v8 and i faced next problem - i have an application which running a javascript file ( i simply read it into a string and than execute with

```
Local<String> source = String::New(javascript); //javascript is string with js file
Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
Local<Value> result = script->Run();
```

how can I send a string variable into this file?

Comment: where does the string need to be inserted? at the beginning, at the end, somewhere in the middle?

Comment: it has to be inserted instead a js string ar the beginning of the script. but I already solved this problem by putting var str = " " into a js and replacing it with value which have to setted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a placeholder in the script source, like `STRING_HERE`. Then, before creating the source object, find that placeholder in the string and replace it with the string value you want.

Comment: so I should put mplaceholder into my JS file like this

`
function Process(){

var theElement = document.getElementById("myPlaceholder");
...
}
`
and then after reading this file into a C++ string just simply replace it with the variable which I want to send? that's it?