# how to send string data into a javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++

I am using v8 and i faced next problem - i have an application which running a javascript file ( i simply read it into a string and than execute with

```
Local<String> source = String::New(javascript); //javascript is string with js file    
Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(source); 
Local<Value> result = script->Run();
```

how can I send a string variable into this file?

Comment: Voted to close as this is better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send string data into a javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980483/how-to-send-string-data-into-a-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you can try prepending the necessary javascript statements onto your javascript code before you stringify and compile. Another option is to use [an accessor](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#accesssors) which you assign to the context and will tie back to read/write methods in your code.